# Multidimensional Collections for a (CS) Graph Class Interface in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, graph, computer-science

For jollies I'm trying to implement a graph data structure as an interface, so that I can implement graph classes either as adjacency lists (lists of lists of edges) or as adjacency matrices ( a 2 dimensional array of edges) with a minimum of additional code.

My question is, is there a way I can implement the IGraph interface so that either this:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<IEdge>>
```

or this:

```
IEdge[,]
```

will be valid types?  I have everything else thought out except this.

Comment: By "will be valid types", do you mean "will implement IGraph"?  If so, no: you can't retrofit an interface to an existing class, even if it happens to have members which fit the interface definition.  If not, could you clarify where you want these types to "be valid"?

Answer (score 1):

So you are using BCL Generics for the linked list. The `LinkedList<LinkedList<IEdge>>` structure should work just fine.